# How to serve several different directories in Angular Dart project?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to set up several configurations in my Angular Dart project, to make it possible to serve and build different versions of Angular application from several different top level directories (apart from standard `web` directory)
For a demonstration I've created standard Angular Dart application from template ( https://github.com/vadimtsushko/two_configs_test ), and have copied `web` directory to `web2`.
I can successfully run application from `web` directory with `pub run build_runner serve web:8080`.
Now I add config file `build.web2.yaml` with such content:

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        # These are globs for the entrypoints you want to compile.
        generate_for:
          - web2/**.dart
```

After that I run this new `web2` configuration, hoping that would serve application from `web2` directory with such command:
`pub run build_runner serve --config=web2 web2:8080`
But I get a warning:

```
[WARNING] Requested a server for `web2` but this directory has no assets in the build. You may need to add some sources or include this directory in some target in your `build.yaml`
Serving `web2` on http://localhost:8080
```

I definitely have source file ( `main.dart` ) in `web2` directory. I've included `web2` in a target in `build.web2.yaml` but apparently something is wrong with that config file.

What changes should I make in my `build.web2.yaml` file to make it work?

Comment: While I still don't have an answer to this question I've solved original problem of setting up several app configurations by restructuring my project. I've ended up with project scturture with main angular repository without any entrypoint and children projects in apps subdirectory. Children projects contain just their corresponding entrypoints in their web directories. Example is in https://github.com/vadimtsushko/two_configs_test/tree/restructured (on restructured branch)

Comment: Benefits of such arrangements are twofolds. Firslty we can use totally standard workflow and secondly (and probably more important) children projects have independend .dart_tools directories, and don't mess with each other in their serve and build process

Comment: Thank for your solution. I had almost the same problem. I had two independent Angular Dart modules and PhpStorm was unable to Run/Debug them as it generated same configuration for both. The solution is to have only one subproject with two subdirectories which distinguish the configurations. See my QA https://stackoverflow.com/a/55848621/1444083. Maybe someone will find it useful.