# PhpStorm - Two Dart web apps in one project

Tags: dart, phpstorm, webstorm, angular-dart

I have a Dart project in PhpStorm and I have two web (Angular Dart) modules (or subprojects?)

I have a problem how to run/debug them as PhpStorm created very same JavaScript Debug configurations. When I had only one it worked well.

Directory structure is
`~/Zdrojaky/src/dart/app/Vavrinec` (the main project) with two subdirs `Admin` and `Owner`. Run/Debug conf is same for both.

Is it possible to Run/Debug two web Angular Dart (or JS) apps in one PhpStorm project? I would expect different port or directory in URL.

[image].
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found almost the same SO question by Vadim Tsushko [How to serve several different directories in Angular Dart project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55533382/1444083) and his solution guided me. The (only?) solution is to have all Angular Dart modules in only one PhpStorm project. So I created a `Client` project and moved `Admin` and `Owner` as normal subdirectories to this. No `.idea` directories in `Admin` and `Owner`. The directory structure is `~/Zdrojaky/src/dart/app/Vavrinec` (the main project) with `Client` subdir (subproject) with two subdirs `Admin` and `Owner`. The Run/Debug configs are then distinguished by the directories names and works as expected.

[image]
[image]
[image]